# Dynamic Schema Processing - Pentaho Session

Tags: security, session, pentaho, cube

I have used the Dynamic Schema Processing in Pentaho.
I can see see the restriction in the Cube ( saiku report )  but the problem is with user session ( I have a result of the last connected user until I refresh the cube again )

Is it possible to get rid of the refreshing task ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Saiku**

I had the same problem in Saiku and I solved it by setting the attribute userAware to true on `biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/saiku/plugin.spring.xml` :

```xml
<bean id="connectionManager" class="org.saiku.plugin.PentahoSecurityAwareConnectionManager" init-method="init">
     <property name="dataSourceManager" ref="pentahoDsManager" />
     <property name="userAware" value="true" />
     <property name="connectionPooling" value="true" />
</bean>
```

**CDA**

I also have the same problem with CDA, it is not refreshing/updating the schema when a user log in. It always use the same schema from the first user logged-in. I haven't found any solution about that...